# how to read template excel file and save as different file using Openxml without modifying the old file?

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml

I have a requirement in which let say we have one excel template in which some fields needs to fill up with their corresponding values. After writing the data in that excel file , we want to save that as different file without modifying the existing template and close the excel.

I am using OpenXML SDK  to read and edit excel files in DOT Net Core. I have figure out one way to solve this requirement by first copying the template into new file then editing that template using OpenXML and save it.

Note: doc.SaveAs("newfile.xltx")  // This will create new file but also makes the changes in the existing template. So this cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.Copy("template.xltx", "newfile.xltx");

using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("newfile.xltx", true))
{
    WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
    
    //Do work here to fill in fields.
    
    //This will save the changes made in newfile.xltx without changing the template.
    wbPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

I would love to know if there is any other way of doing it.